Printing Report from SSRS via a Stored Procedure
I am working on creating a stored procedure that exports a pdf report from a SSRS report server. The report needs a parameter called "ExportId". The procedure runs successfully but it does not create a pdf. What am I doing wrong here?

Alter PROCEDURE rsp_GenerateAndDeliverReports
    @ReportName NVARCHAR(100),
    @Parameter1Name NVARCHAR(100),
    @Parameter1Value NVARCHAR(100),
    @OutputFile NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Variables
    DECLARE @executionID AS INT
    DECLARE @reportBytes AS VARBINARY(MAX)
    DECLARE @zipFilePath AS NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @reportService AS INT -- Change the data type to INT

    -- Create an instance of the SSRS Execution Service
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'SSRS.ReportExecutionService', @reportService OUT

    -- Initialize the service
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @reportService, 'Url', 'http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx'

    -- Load Report 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @reportService, 'LoadReport', NULL, @ReportName, NULL, @executionID OUT

    -- Set Report 1 Parameters
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @reportService, 'SetExecutionParameters', NULL, @Parameter1Name, @Parameter1Value

    -- Render Report 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @reportService, 'Render', @reportBytes OUTPUT, 'PDF', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

    -- Close and release the service
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @reportService





    -- Save Report 1 as PDF
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'DECLARE @file AS VARBINARY(MAX) 
                SET @file = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @reportBytes, 1) + '
                EXEC sp_writebytesfile @file, ''' + @OutputFile + ''
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END


EXEC rsp_GenerateAndDeliverReports @ReportName='/All Reports/Subreports/07_sub', @Parameter1Name ='ExportId', @Parameter1Value='2', @OutputFile='C:\Users\Public\Public Downloads\Report.pdf'




Why all those OA methods? Why not use a subscription?

If you insist on using the OA-methods, it would behoove you to check for errors returned from them

Don't do it. On what planet does this logic belong in a database? There is a reason it's difficult, because you shouldn't be doing it. Write yourself a small service or scheduled task. You'll have more control, be easier to debug, be extendable, and most importantly not bugger up your database.

Use a SQL Agent Job and a PowerShell script instead.  Really, it's much simpler and more robust.  From TSQL write the report request to a table, and then call sp_start_job or have a schedule kick off an Agent job to render all the pending report export requests.
If you want to know how to use the sp_oaxxx procedures, see here.
And using the SSRS SOAP API is gross overkill for report export.  Just user URL Access, and you can get a rendered report just by sending a single HTTP GET to a URL.
